# Run-time error '-2147221020 (800401e4)' MSXML.send error

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

```
Sub ScrapData()
Dim TeamName As String
Dim TeamURL As String
Dim MSXML As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim DOC As New HTMLDocument, Cell As Range
TeamName = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value
If TeamName = "" Then
MsgBox "Team Name can't be null", vbExclamation
Exit Sub
End If
Set Cell = Sheet1.Range("D:D").Find(what:=TeamName, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
    TeamURL = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
    LName = GetRightCode(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
    DoEvents
    MSXML.Open "GET", TeamURL
    **MSXML.send**
    DoEvents
    DOC.body.innerHTML = MSXML.responseText
    Set Tbl1 = DOC.getElementById("table_v1")
    Set Tbl2 = DOC.getElementById("table_v2")
    Set StTbl = DOC.getElementById("table_v3")
```

I get the error on MSXML.send. It was working some months ago but now it appears this error.

Any help?

Comment: Difficult to say with no URL but it's possible the URL is malformed...

Comment: yeah you were right. Ty for the warning. it was hhttp instead of http thats why he got the error LOL

Comment: Please, clarify your question. It is needed more explanation.